# New connection for each query or one connection for all queries? (CommandBehavior.CloseConnection vs CommandBehavior.Default)

Tags: c#, .net, sql, ado.net, sql-server-ce

I'm developing a text analysis desktop application, that intensively queries local database (MSSQLCE 3.5). As the user throws text in, it should react in real-time, so I'm using ADO.NET with pure SQL and trying to get the best performance results.

The question is: based on my task, should I keep ONE cached connection (as static variable or singleton) and make queries with `CommandBehavior.Default` or should I build a new connection for each query and specify `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection`?

I know that usually it's recommended to close connection ASAP, but should I really do it, if there can be thousands of queries per minute, for example when user pastes a huge text?

Until now, application worked on CloseConnection. Now I tried to turn it to CommandBehavior.Default with single connection. I can see some small performance speed-up and can't see any problems at this time, but I want to know if there are any strings attached, before I put this to deployment.

```
// one cached connection for all queries
private static DbConnection _connection = null;
public static String MakeQuery()
{            
    if (_connection == null)
    {
        _connection = new SqlCeConnection(...);
        _connection.Open();
    }
    var cmd = new SqlCeCommand("...", _connection);
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default))
    { 

    }
}
```

vs.

```
// new connection for each query
public static String MakeQuery()
{            
    using (var connection = new SqlCeConnection(...))
    {
       connection.Open();            
       var cmd = new SqlCeCommand("...", connection);
       using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
       { 
           ...
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, when I need many queries in a rapid succession from a non-web application, I prefer to use one shared connection.

The only problem is that you have to keep an eye on it because it may go down unexpectedly due to a network problem <s>or because SQL server thought it better be closed</s>. That is, you must handle StateChanged events.

<s>But [connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) is on by default anyway. It should be handling all these issues for you. Yes, pooling does add an overhead, but it's not big.</s>

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer! I will look on StateChanged, but I would like to know more on why and when SQL server can decide to close the connection unexpectedly. Also, I'm not completely sure that SQL Compact Edition 3.5 SP2 provider supports pooling. The link you gave tells about (SQL SERVER 2008).

Comment: @lonelyass This article made me think it's ADO.NET that maintains the pool, not the actual data provider... [I might be wrong](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30031355/sql-compact-edition--connection-pool--slow.aspx). Regarding closing the connection unexpectedly, it seems I was wrong, as [CE doesn't have a deadlock detection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172453(v=SQL.100).aspx). I'm striking this part out in my answer.

Comment: I found a very nice research on my topic: http://csharponphone.blogspot.com/2007/01/keeping-sqlceconnection-open-and-thread.html

You can use one SqlCeConnection to improve perfomance, BUT SqlCeConnection is NOT OFFICIALLY THREAD SAFE, so you have to make a thread-safe wrapper for db-access, if you want to use this strategy. 

"An interesting side note: I created a test app on the mobile phone which launched 50 threads on a shared SqlCeConnection and proceeded to read/write random bits of data. No exception was thrown. Of course, the lack of error does not mean that it will always work."